# IValidatableObject vs Single Responsibility

Tags: architecture, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, validation, single-responsibility

I like the extnesibility point of MVC, allowing view models to implement IValidatableObject, and add custom validation.

I try to keep my Controllers lean, having this code be the only validation logic:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(loginViewModel);
```

For example a login view model implements IValidatableObject, gets ILoginValidator object via constructor injection:

```
public interface ILoginValidator
{
    bool UserExists(string email);
    bool IsLoginValid(string userName, string password);
}
```

It seems that Ninject, injecting instances in view models isn't really a common practice, may be even an anti-pattern?

Is this a good approach? Is there a better one?

Comment: If you want the validation in a separate object, try FluentValidation. See http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc.

Comment: +1 Great idea to inject a separate Validator class, that solves my problem where I have to access database information for validation!

Answer (score 7):

Personally, to me your design seems clean.

IValidatableObject means the view model will provide some validation that can't be provided by simple attributes - injecting the real validator which will call services / databases / whatever keeps your design clean and ensures you *don't* violate the single responsibility principle - View Models are responsible, essentially, for transferring data and validating the data that is transferred (whether it be through attributes or IValidatableObject or both).

Answer (score 4):

Having a dedicated object for validation guarantees that you respect SRP indeed - which was already the case anyway since it's a typical responsibility of a view model to validate its data.

As for injecting instances into view models, I can't see anything wrong with that. There's virtually no limit to what can be injected into what.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of injecting the ILoginValidator into your VM constructor you can use the ValidationContext (which is the arg to IValidatableObject.Validate()) to get your Validator.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext vc)
{

var loginValidator = (ILoginValidator)vc.GetService(typeof(ILoginValidator));
return loginValidator.Validate();

}
```